# split an array which comtains partially relatively order into two sorted array in O(n) time

Tags: algorithm, sorting, split

Assume I have two arrays, both of them are sorted, for example:

`A: [1, 4, 5, 8, 10, 24]`

`B: [3, 6, 9, 29, 50, 65]`

And then I merge these two array into one array and keep original relative order of both two array

`C: [1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 29, 10, 24, 50, 65]`

Is there any way to split C into two sorted array in O(n) time?

note: not necessarily into the original A and B

Comment: There's ways to split them, but not necessarily into the original `A` and `B` without more information. For instance, we could end up getting `[1,4,5,6,9,29]` and `[3,8,10,24,50,65]` as possible splits in the above example, among many others.

Comment: Yes, not necessarily into the original A and B, can you give me a hint?

Comment: Are the two sorted arrays STRICTLY increasing (are all elements distinct)?

Comment: Yes, you can assume the two original arrays are STRICTLY increasing

Comment: A greedy approach would work: for each element in `C`, try to put it in the first sorted array. If you can't, then the element has to go into the second sorted array. This scheme works but proving why would be interesting.

Comment: Oh, that's an interesting idea and the time complexity is exactly O(n)

Answer (score 2):

Greedily assign your integers to list 1 if they can go there. If they can't, assign them to list 2.

Here's some Ruby code to play around with this idea. It randomly splits the integers from 0 to n-1 into two sorted lists, then randomly merges them, then applies the greedy approach.

```
def f(n)
 split1 = []
 split2 = []
 0.upto(n-1) do |i|
   if rand < 0.5
     split1.append(i)
   else
     split2.append(i)
   end
 end
 
 puts "input 1: #{split1.to_s}"
 puts "input 2: #{split2.to_s}"
 
 merged = []
 split1.reverse!
 split2.reverse!
 while split1.length > 0 && split2.length > 0
    if rand < 0.5
     merged.append(split1.pop)
   else
     merged.append(split2.pop)
   end
 end
 merged += split1.reverse
 merged += split2.reverse
 
 puts "merged: #{merged.to_s}"
 
 merged.reverse!
 
 greedy1 = [merged.pop]
 greedy2 = []
 
 while merged.length > 0
   if merged[-1] >= greedy1[-1]
     greedy1.append(merged.pop)
   else
     greedy2.append(merged.pop)
   end
 end
 
 puts "greedy1: #{greedy1.to_s}"
 puts "greedy2: #{greedy2.to_s}"
end
```

Here's sample output:

```
> f(20)
input 1: [2, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 10, 18, 19]
input 2: [0, 1, 6, 7, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]
merged: [2, 0, 1, 6, 3, 4, 5, 8, 9, 7, 10, 11, 18, 12, 13, 19, 14, 15, 16, 17]
greedy1: [2, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 18, 19]
greedy2: [0, 1, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17]

> f(20)
input 1: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15]
input 2: [0, 2, 4, 7, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
merged: [0, 2, 4, 7, 12, 14, 16, 1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 17, 9, 18, 10, 19, 11, 13, 15]
greedy1: [0, 2, 4, 7, 12, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19]
greedy2: [1, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 11, 13, 15]

> f(20)
input 1: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18]
input 2: [3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19]
merged: [3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 0, 13, 16, 17, 1, 19, 2, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18]
greedy1: [3, 4, 5, 8, 10, 12, 13, 16, 17, 19]
greedy2: [0, 1, 2, 6, 7, 9, 11, 14, 15, 18]
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's take your example.

```
[1, 4, 3, 5, 6, 9, 8, 29, 10, 24, 50, 65]
```

In time `O(n)` you can work out the minimum of the tail.

```
[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 24, 50, 65]
```

And now the one stream is all cases where it is the minimum, and the other is the cases where it isn't.

```
[1,    3, 5, 6,    8,     10, 24, 50, 65]
[   4,          9,    29,               ]
```

This is all doable in time `O(n)`.

We can go further and now split into 3 streams based on which values in the first stream could have gone in the last without changing it being increasing.

```
[      3, 5, 6,    8,     10, 24,       ]
[1,       5, 6,    8,             50, 65]
[   4,          9,    29,               ]
```

And now we can start enumerating the `2^6 = 64` different ways of splitting the original stream back into 2 increasing streams.

Comment: When I get the array `[1, 3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 8, 10, 10, 24, 50, 65]`, is the next step to compare this array with the original one? I don't fully understand how to split the array like this 
`[1,    3, 5, 6,    8,     10, 24, 50, 65]
  [   4,          9,    29,               ]`
in your next step